# Что значит "дом апостола из семидесяти"?

Tags: значение-слов

> Раскопки под церковью *Santa Pudenziana* до сих пор не закончены, но
>   известно, что под уровнем пола базилики, на глубине девяти метров,
>   **спит дом апостола из семидесяти**. Мощи апостола Пуда и его сыновей
>   Новатуса и Тимофея покоятся под алтарём храма, там же, где и частицы
>   тела его дочери – Святой Пуденцианы.

И на этом перечисление окончено.

Это "апостол из семидесяти" или его "дом" из семидесяти домочадцев?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это апостол из семидесяти.

Апостолы из семидесяти – последователи Иисуса Христа, проповедавшие его учение в I веке (кроме двенадцати апостолов и апостола Павла).

> После сего избрал Господь и других семьдесят [учеников], и послал их
>   по два пред лицем Своим во всякий город и место, куда Сам хотел идти,
>   и сказал им: жатвы много, а делателей мало; итак, молите Господина
>   жатвы, чтобы выслал делателей на жатву Свою.
>   *(Лк. 10:1-2)*

[Апостолы от семидесяти](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B_%D0%BE%D1%82_%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8).

Comment: О! Так надо предлог поправить? С *из* на *от*?

Comment: Скорее всего да. Видимо, в церковной традиции так принятно, если даже статья в википедии так называется. Хотя если текст не церковный, то, думаю, что можно и оставить "из". Я бы оставил :)